# Parse HTTP packets in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm using the node.js net library which gives me access to the raw data it receives. I happen to know in some cases it will be an HTTP packet and am wondering what the best way to parse it is. Ideally there would be some sort of library?

```
var socket = net.connect(port, listener);
socket.on('data', function(data) {
   // If I know data is an HTTP packet how do I parse it and do something like below?
   // var packet = lib.parse(data);
   // console.log(packet.host);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use the HTTP module?

Comment: The short answer is I'm working at a lower layer. In some cases it won't be an HTTP packet.